# Cannot download attachment in response from server

Tags: ios, swift, client-server, httpresponse, alamofire

I have used post method in Alamofire to upload a file successfully, and I get the response from server, I can see the attachment hiding in response. When I'm trying to save the attachment in my computer, it doesn't work. Here is the code:

```
let urlRequest = urlRequestWithComponents(URL, parameters: parameters, imageData: fileData!)
Alamofire.upload(urlRequest.0, urlRequest.1)
    .progress { (bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite) in
        println("\(totalBytesWritten) / \(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)")
    }
    .response { (request, response, data, error) in
        println("REQUEST \(request)")
        println("RESPONSE \(response)")
        println("JSON \(data)")
        println("ERROR \(error)")
```

Here is the file in attachment I got from the server:

```
"Content-Disposition" = "attachment; filename=20150113171557120001.mid";
```

And the data shows exactly the right .mid file

> JSON Optional(<4d546864 00000006 00000001 00044d54 726b0000 00540391 35350381 35350291 3a3a0281 3a3a0291 3c3c0381 3c3c0191 3e3e0381 3e3e0691 3e3e0381 3e3e0891 3e3e0381 3e3e0291 3c3c0381 3c3c0191 3d3d0381 3d3d0191 3a3a0381 3a3a0691 3a3a0381 3a3a00ff 2f00>)
>
> ERROR nil

Here is the code I use to save the attachment in my computer:

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSArray
let documentsDirectory = paths.objectAtIndex(0) as NSString
let path = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("file.mid")
 (data as NSData).writeToFile(path, atomically:true)
```

After I add the code of saving the attachment, there are no errors or warnings, while on output except for a thread showing like this:

> thread1 exc_breakpoint(code=exc_i386_BPT, subcode=0x0)

Am I using the wrong method to save the attachment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your hex representation, that looks like a MIDI file (it starts with the right bytes).

The problem is:

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSArray
let documentsDirectory = paths.objectAtIndex(0) as NSString
```

You're getting the "first item" twice. That item you're trying to return as `paths` is not the paths array, but rather the first string in that array (because you included the `[0]` at the end). Thus, the attempt to cast that as an array will fail (much less the attempt to later grab the first item from it).

Simpler would be:

```
let documentsDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use url instead of paths

```
let documentsUrl =  NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first as NSURL
let fileUrl = documentsUrl.URLByAppendingPathComponent("file.mid")
data.writeToURL(fileUrl, atomically:true)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot ^ ^! I'm a beginner, and you give me a new solution!